# Cache a bluetooth connection iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am new to bluetooth dev in iOS. I have successfully connected my iOS device to an external bluetooth 4.0 (BLE) device using CoreBluetooth and the `CBCentralManager`.

However, every time I exit the app or close it or whatever, I lose the connection and next time the app opens, I have to redo all the initial steps for connecting all over again.

So my question is this, how do I "Cache" a bluetooth connection on the iOS side? Maybe cache is not the right term, I am just looking for a way to remember the connection after the first time I connect the iOS app to the external bluetooth device.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like there's two possible factors at play here:

**1) Background Mode**

If you want Bluetooth connections to stay alive (and continue advertising, if you're using `CBPeripheralManager`) after closing the app, you would need to add either the `bluetooth-central` or `bluetooth-peripheral` background mode to your Info.plist file. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html) for more information on Bluetooth background modes.

Seeing as you mentioned using `CBCentralManager` on the iOS side, the appropriate backround mode in your case would be `bluetooth-central`.

**2) State Restoration**

Both `CBCentralManager` and `CBPeripheralManager` have an initialization option that allows you to specify a restoration identifier. For `CBCentralManager`, you would pass a dictionary containing a unique identifier for the key `CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey` into the options parameter of `-initWithDelegate:queue:options`.

Then when your app is relaunched in the background, you simply need to re-instantiate the `CBCentralManager` instance with the previously specified restoration identifier to restore the previous state. More information on state restoration can be found in the [same document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html).